# What Recourse Do I Have Against Fraudulent Ecommerce? [UK]

Tags: united-kingdom, fraud

Very simple question, I'm surprised it hasn't been asked before.

I bought a product form a website a month ago.

They confirmed my order, took the payment and gave me an order number... and that's it.

Since they took the payment, they haven't given me any updates as to why it's taking so long, they've made it really hard to get into contact with them and haven't responded to me (I'm not even sure if I'm reaching out to them correctly, I guessed they had a .info email address and also they have a Facebook group of the same name).

At this point I feel they are a dead business, but they're still accepting orders and taking payments for a big exit-scam. I want to get a refund before it's too late, their website is still up and running. What can I do to get my money back (as it was taken through a debit card payment).

Comment: This happened to me with the *government of Canada getting an eTa visa online*.  "!"  Cost me five bucks I never ever got back and no recourse.

Comment: The solution for this is to go through your payment method.  They should refund your money and pass the charges onto the provider.

Answer (score 4):

If the business is based in the UK and you have an address, you should write to them directly by post demanding your product or your money back and making it clear you'll take them to court if they don't comply. If that doesn't help then you can [issue a "small claim" against them](https://www.gov.uk/make-court-claim-for-money).

Whether or not they are in the UK, you can also try to use the ["chargeback" scheme](https://www.which.co.uk/consumer-rights/advice/how-do-i-use-chargeback) to get the debit card transaction reversed. As this isn't a statutory right there's no strong guarantee it'll work, but it's worth trying. If you'd used a credit card your rights would have been stronger under ["section 75"](https://www.which.co.uk/consumer-rights/regulation/section-75-of-the-consumer-credit-act).

Comment: For chargeback reasons it is better to use credit not debit cards. Easier to claim back.

Comment: @Mark agreed, but too late for that now